# How to validate from controller

Tags: cakephp

In my application I did not have model.am using webservice for data.To handle the exception I need use $this->invalidate from controller. Without model how to use that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`invalidate()` is a method from AppModel, so it must be called against a model.  If you're doing validation, why aren't you using a model?

Answer (score 0):

For using a webservice other patterns work much better. For example you could build a custom datasource:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/datasources.html

That's the best solution in most cases. Now you put everything in a controller and that will cause issues.

So the advised structure for the data flow is:

```
datasource -> model (with optionally a behaviour) -> controller
```

If it's a common webservice I would suggest that you put the datasource in a plugin to seperate it out. Like: https://github.com/cakephp/datasources as an example (be aware they're a but old). See for example this one as a more recent: https://github.com/dkullmann/CakePHP-Elastic-Search-DataSource

In general you tried to put all in the controller to keep it simple I suspect but it is advised to structure it according to the framework.